# Stored procedure doesn't return dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to execute a stored procedure from C# and get a DataSet. The stored procedure using a `SELECT` statement works very well, but when using `INSERT INTO` command, the dataset returned is empty but the data is, in fact, inserted into the database. Some suggestions?

This is the stored procedure;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_add_Indicator
    @Rut AS NCHAR(10),
    @Escuela NVARCHAR(50),
    @Indicador NVARCHAR(50),
    @Fecha NVARCHAR(50),
    @Comuna NVARCHAR(50),
    @Codigo NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO IndicadoresCaso (RutAlumno, Escuela, Indicador, FechaIngresoCaso, Comuna, Codigo) 
    VALUES (@Rut, @Escuela, @Indicador, @Fecha, @Comuna, @Codigo)
```

This is my C# code:

```
DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_stringConnection))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("sp_add_Indicator", conn);
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rut", "999999999");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Escuela", "Any school");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Indicador", "Any Indicator");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", "Any date");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comuna", "Any Comuna");
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", "Any Code");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
        da.Fill(dsDataSet);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: A.SQL insert doesn't return a result set (run you SQL statement in SQL Server Management Studio and you'll see it). As a result, you won't get a dataset back. Instead of trying to fill a dataset, just run the command

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Dan Guzman says: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to return the row you just inserted and the IndicadoresCaso table has an identity column called IndicadoresCasoID then your stored procedure could do the following:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_add_Indicator
    @Rut AS NCHAR(10),
    @Escuela NVARCHAR(50),
    @Indicador NVARCHAR(50),
    @Fecha NVARCHAR(50),
    @Comuna NVARCHAR(50),
    @Codigo NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO IndicadoresCaso (RutAlumno, Escuela, Indicador, FechaIngresoCaso, Comuna, Codigo) 
    VALUES (@Rut, @Escuela, @Indicador, @Fecha, @Comuna, @Codigo);

    SELECT RutAlumno, Escuela, Indicador, FechaIngresoCaso, Comuna, Codigo
    FROM IndicadoresCaso
    WHERE IndicadoresCasoID = scope_identity();
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect to retrieve from you dataset? The values you have just inserted? You already have them, so why get them again from the dataset?

Anyway for your SP to return a dataset, it must contains a `SELECT` statement. So add statement like:

```sql
SELECT RutAlumno,Escuela,Indicador,FechaIngresoCaso,Comuna,Codigo
FROM IndicadoresCaso
WHERE RutAlumno = @Rut -- AND Escuela = @Escuela ??
```

after your insert. Adapt the WHERE clause to retrieve the row(s) you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure does not contain any SELECT statement, only contains INSERT statement. This is why there's no data is returned after executing the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is made to do only `INSERT` statement.

If you are looking for the inserted data to be returned then after the insert you need to write appropriate select statement (in stored procedure) to select data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTPUT clause of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO IndicadoresCaso 
    (RutAlumno, Escuela, Indicador, FechaIngresoCaso, Comuna, Codigo) 
    OUTPUT 
    Inserted.RutAlumno, Inserted.Escuela, Inserted.Indicador, 
    Inserted.FechaIngresoCaso,Inserted.Comuna, Inserted.Codugo    
VALUES (@Rut, @Escuela, @Indicador, @Fecha, @Comuna, @Codigo);
```